# Jquery Tagit - How to pass the typed tags back to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-post, tag-it

I'm using the following tagit plugin
http://webspirited.com/tagit/

This is the code snippets of the html page that I am trying to test this plugin with - where the user types the tags

```
<input class="text_field" type="text" size="72" id="question_title"/>
<textarea id="question"></textarea>

<ul id="demo3" class="tagit">
<li class="tagit-choice">apple orange<a class="tagit-close">x</a></li>
<li class="tagit-new"><input class="tagit-input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"></li>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul></ul>

<input id="question_submit" type="submit" value="Ask Question"/>
```

Now when the user clicks on "Ask Question" button - the following ajax calls occurs

```
$("#question_submit").live('click',function(e) {            
        e.preventDefault();     
        var question_val = $("#question").val();
        var question_title = $("#question_title").val();

        var tags = $("#demo3").tagit("tags");
        var s ='';
        for (var i in tags)
            s += tags[i].label + " : " + tags[i].value + "\r\n";
        alert(s);

            $.post('/course/ask-question', {question: question_val,question_title: question_title,tags:tags}, function(data) {
                if(data.success=="ok")
                {
                    $("div#wall").prepend(data.question);
                }                   
            },"json");

    });
```

So in this function I'm able to get the tags

```
var tags = $("#demo3").tagit("tags");
```

and loop through them and print the label and value for each tag.

Now when I try to pass it via the $.post to my PHP controller - it doesn't work - I mean if I remove the data tags:tags when calling the ask-question function it works fine - but when I add it - nothin happens as if the function is not being called.

Is there a particular way to pass this tag object to PHP ?

EDIT
In Chrome developer tools - when I submit the form while keeping the tags:tags in the data - I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
e jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
e.extend.each jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
bY jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
f.extend.param jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
f.(anonymous function) jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
(anonymous function) course-feed.js:51
L jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
f.event.handle jquery-1.6.4.min.js:3
i.handle.k
```

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's two easy way to fix this:

1- Set the option 'fieldName' to 'tags[]'

```
$("#myTags").tagit({
    fieldName: 'tags[]'
});
```

2- (less recommanded) Change the js file to always append '[]' to the fileName:

Change each:

```
name="' + this.options.fieldName + '"
```

for:

```
name="' + this.options.fieldName + '[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the document of the plugin you are using, `tags` will be an Array. If using an Array is what you needed, try to change `tags: tags` to `'tags[]':tags` see if it works?

Comment: Thanks Jason - I tried that - its not making any difference - thanks

Comment: If you use Chrome, you can open developer tools to see what the post returns. You can post what it returns here so that we can take a look?

Comment: For firefox, you should be able to use firebug to do the same thing. :-)

Comment: Thanks Jason - I've edited the question to show the error in Chrome

Comment: Is it possible to use a sequence chain rather than an Array for tags?

Comment: You can easily join the array using a separator, for example: `var tagStr = tags.join(",")`, so in your post you can use `tags:tagStr`. Then on the server side, you should be able to separate the sequence chain to the array.

Comment: yes thats always an option - but these tags are going to be label:value pairse - and joining them as a string and parsing them on the server side will result in messy code which I was trying to avoid.